# putting json-simple into my java ant build

Tags: java, json, ant

so I've been trying to put json-simple into my Ant build, but whenever I run my main class, I get this error:

`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException`

I'm assuming my build file is incorrect and it didn't build json-simple. Here is my build.xml:

```
<project default="compile">
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build">   
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="lib/json_simple-1.1.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>
</project>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the name of the jar file.

I believe it should be

`<pathelement path="lib/json-simple-1.1.jar"/>`